# Conditional contour plot

Tags: plotting

I want to plot implicit plots in certain regions. For example plot the section of the hyperbola that is in between the wedge. But I could not find out how to do this. Multiplying the first expression with a <> expression does not work.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `RegionFunction`as an option

```
ContourPlot[x^2/15^2 - y^2/(-15^2 + 37^2) == 1, {x, -50, 50}, {y, -50, 50}, 
RegionFunction ->Function[{x, y},y <= Tan[15 Degree] (x + 37) && y >= - Tan[15 Degree] (x + 37)]]
```

[image]

Comment: How would I have different regions for different implicit functions on the same window?

Comment: Combine ContourPlots using Show or create a RegionFunction with several implicit regions.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [`ConditionalExpression`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ConditionalExpression.html) as follows:

```
ContourPlot[{ConditionalExpression[x^2/15^2 - y^2/(-15^2 + 37^2), 
    Abs[y] <= Tan[15 Degree] (x + 37)] == 1, 
  Abs[y] == Tan[15 Degree] (x + 37)} ,
 {x, -50, 50}, {y, -50, 50}]
```

[image]